# Finding relative offset in nested structure

Tags: c

So, `offsetof(struct, field)` returns the relative offset of field inside a plain structure. But is there a way to get the relative offset of a field inside of a nested structure.

e.g.

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   struct {
      int b;
      int c;
   } anonymous_struct;
}
```

Is there any way to get the offset of `b` and `c` relative to `my_struct` (at runtime).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can still use `offsetof`.

E.g.

```
size_t boff = offsetof(struct my_struct, anonymous_struct.b);
```

The requirements of `offsetof` are that the *type* and *member-designator* must be such that given `static`*type*`t;`, `&(t.`*member-designator*`)` evaluates to an address constant. The *member-designator* doesn't have to be a simple identifier.

Comment: That was the only combination I failed to try. 10x